# How to get the wave height of a gerstner shader made in shader graph?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have followed this gerstner wave shader graph tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/Awd1hRpLSoI).

I am now trying to implement buoyancy by attaching the following script to a gameobject (taken from [this](https://youtu.be/eL_zHQEju8s) tutorial).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Floater : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rigidBody;
    public float depthBeforeSubmerged = 1f;
    public float displacementAmount = 3f;
    public int floaterCount = 1;
    public float waterDrag = 0.99f;
    public float waterAngularDrag = 0.5f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(Physics.gravity / floaterCount, transform.position, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        float waveHeight = WaveManager.instance.GetWaveHeight();

        if (transform.position.y < waveHeight)
        {
            float displacementMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01((waveHeight - transform.position.y) / depthBeforeSubmerged) * displacementAmount;
            rigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(0f, Mathf.Abs(Physics.gravity.y) * displacementMultiplier, 0f), transform.position, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            rigidBody.AddForce(displacementMultiplier * -rigidBody.velocity * waterDrag * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            rigidBody.AddTorque(displacementMultiplier * -rigidBody.angularVelocity * waterAngularDrag * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code you use `float waveHeight = WaveManager.instance.GetWaveHeight();` to obtain the wave height from the relevant function in the WaveManager script below, which is attached to the gerstner wave gameobject (just a subdivided plane with the shader graph material applied).

```
public class WaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static WaveManager instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != this)
        {
            Debug.Log("Instance already exists, destroying object!");
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }

    public float GetWaveHeight()
    {
       // The formula will go here.
    }
}
```

**You are meant to use the same formula in the GetWaveHeight() function as in the shader graph.**

The problem is I don't know how to achieve this.

The following screenshots illustrate the gerstner wave shader graph setup that I have currently.

To clarify, there are 4 separate gerstner waves layered on top of each other to make it more realistic, so that will need to be incorporated into the formula.

**Frequency Subgraph**

[image: Frequency Subgraph]

**Theta Subgraph**

[image: Theta Subgraph]

**Displacement Subgraph**

[image: Displacement Subgraph]

**GerstnerWave Subgraph**

[image: GerstnerWave Subgraph]

**NewNormal Subgraph**

[image: NewNormal Subgraph]

**Gerstner Shader Graph (in 3 sections; top, middle and bottom as it was so large)**

[image: Top]

[image: Middle]

[image: Bottom]

Any advice is appreciated. I know this may be a complicated issue, so let me know if need to clarify anything.

## The project is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/MagnalityMusic/Bracing).

*I am using a boat model to test the buoyancy, it has 4 gameobjects with the Floater script attached.*

Thank you!

Comment: I think there's no direct way converting the shadergraph to a `GetHeight(Vector2)` function because the shader works by shifting points in the mesh in the x and z positions as well as y, so it's not easy to "look up" the height from a given (x,z) position. Either you need a simpler wave system that just does vertical displacement, or maybe something like rendering your waves to a `RenderTexture` with the pixel colours representing the height of the waves, and then reading the texture values to find the waves height

Comment: I've just attempted going the 'RenderTexture' route however the lag is so unbearable that I can't tell if I did it correctly. I read up that it is an intensive process reading from the GPU to the CPU constantly. I really want to use this layered gerstner system as sine waves won't be interesting enough for the type of game I wish to create.

Comment: Using render textures isn't cheap but adding just one shouldn't cause any major performance issues. You should just add one, with a reasonably small resolution that is only rendering the water mesh from above using an orthogonal camera and read out the depth values. Just a heads up that the RenderTexture method I'm suggesting is pretty involved and so it might be easier to try to reimplement your gerstner algorithm in C#, and get around the (x,z) issues by interpolating nearby values. If you click on "View generated shader" on the shadergraph it will give you a good start for converting to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok let me help you a little

```
public float HyperbolicTangent(float x)
{
    float exp2x = Mathf.Exp(2 * x);
    return (exp2x - 1) / (exp2x + 1);
}

private float Frequency(Vector3 direction)
{
    float length = direction.magnitude;
    float gLength = gravity * length;

    float dLength = depth * length;
    float  hyperbolicTang = HyperbolicTangent(dLength);

    return Mathf.Sqrt(hyperbolicTang * gLength);
}

private float Theta(Vector3 position, float timing, Vector3 direction)
{
    float positionDirectionX = position.x * direction.x;
    float positionDirectionZ = position.z * direction.z;

    float sum = positionDirectionX + positionDirectionZ;

    float multFrequency = Frequency(direction) * timing;

    return sum - multFrequency - phase;
}

private Vector3 GerstnerWave(Vector3 position, Vector3 direction, float amlitude, float timing)
{
    float theta = Theta(position, timing, direction);

    float GetCoordinate(float axisCoordinate)
    {
        float amplitudePerHyperbolicLengthX = amlitude / HyperbolicTangent(direction.magnitude * depth);

        float directionXToLength = axisCoordinate / direction.magnitude;

        return Mathf.Sin(theta) * directionXToLength * amplitudePerHyperbolicLengthX;
    }

    float GetY()
    {
        return Mathf.Cos(theta) * amlitude;
    }

    return new Vector3(-GetCoordinate(direction.x), GetY(), -GetCoordinate(direction.z));
}

private Vector3 Displacement(Vector3 position, float timing)
{
    Vector3 gerstnerWave1 = GerstnerWave(position, direction1, amlitude1, timing);
    Vector3 gerstnerWave2 = GerstnerWave(position, direction2, amlitude2, timing);
    Vector3 gerstnerWave3 = GerstnerWave(position, direction3, amlitude3, timing);
    Vector3 gerstnerWave4 = GerstnerWave(position, direction4, amlitude4, timing);

    return gerstnerWave1 + gerstnerWave2 + gerstnerWave3 + gerstnerWave4;
}

public Vector3 GetResultVector(Vector3 position, float timing)
{
    Vector3 result = Displacement(position, timing);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This did it for me as this seemingly simulates the shader graph formula accurately! I will update the GitHub link with the working project for others.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have the direction of the wave, the amplitude, and its speed. In fact, you can imitate. Create 4 waves as structures on the c# side, and pass the value of each wave to each of them, and in theory find the height on the sharp side. But that's just my guess

Comment: I've attempted this a few times, however I don't think I'm knowledgable enough to correctly implement the shadergraph formula in C#. I can't seem to get the formula right.